# MYSQL: Only return the latest record of each group based on date

Tags: mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables. One table with companies. The other table with officers. I want to show the company with their current officer.

Each company has a history of officers. The company table looks like this:

```
 -------------------------------
| company_number | name         |
|-------------------------------|
| B1204_GnR103   | Flower LLC   |
| B1204_GnR104   | Marketing LLC|
 -------------------------------
```

The officer table looks like this:

```
 -----------------------------------------------
| id | name         | company_id   | start_date |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| 1  | John Doe     | B1204_GnR103 | 2018-02-06 |
| 2  | Dianne Ameter| B1204_GnR104 | 2017-01-07 |
| 3  | Dylan Mering | B1204_GnR103 | 2016-04-23 |
| 4  | Fleece Gold  | B1204_GnR103 | 2019-05-12 |
| 5  | Frank Kern   | B1204_GnR104 | 2019-09-18 |
| 6  | Andreas Frank| B1204_GnR104 | 2017-03-08 |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

I tried a subselect but I'm not able to make it work.

I tried the following statement but got an error message.

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT company.name, 
        officer.name,
        officer.start_date
FROM company
INNER JOIN officer ON company.company_number =  
                        (SELECT officer.name,
                        DATE_FORMAT(officer.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date
                        FROM officer 
                        WHERE company.company_number = officer.company_id
                        ORDER BY date
                        LIMIT 1)
```

The output should be the following:

```
Company Name | Officer 
----------------------------
Flower LLC   | Fleece Gold
Marketing LLC| Frank Kern
```

Because these persons are the ones with the latest start date and are the current officer of the company.

But I am getting an error message "Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

I'm grateful for any advice, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` your `company` and `officer` tables to a derived table of maximum `start_date` per company to get your desired result:

```
SELECT c.name AS company,
       o.name AS officer,
       o.start_date
FROM company c
JOIN officer o ON o.company_id = c.company_number
JOIN (SELECT company_id, MAX(start_date) AS start_date
      FROM officer
      GROUP BY company_id) m ON m.company_id = o.company_id AND m.start_date = o.start_date
```

Output:

```
company         officer         start_date
Flower LLC      Fleece Gold     2019-05-12 00:00:00
Marketing LLC   Frank Kern      2019-09-18 00:00:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/djtoLCYhXerScmrnUpggJp/1)